# Reading launchSettings.json in .NET Core project?

Tags: json, .net-core, console-application, settings

I have finally started my transition to .NET Core and need some quick help with getting to the `environmentVariables` section of the `launchSettings.json` file. Googling indicates pretty much all NetCore is currently ASP.NET Core whereas I'm currently spiking with libraries and console apps myself.

Is there no API for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`launchSettings.json` is a configuration file on how to launch ASP.NET Core applications. If you're looking for a .NET Core alternative to `app.config` for a console application, have a look at `appSettings.json`.

A (simple) example can be found here [Using strongly typed configuration in .NET Core console app](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/fkaduk/2017/02/22/using-strongly-typed-configuration-in-net-core-console-app/)

Comment: Thanks! Just what I was looking for. Having the correct concepts in place also helped me find this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=basicconfiguration